# Online videos of shiurim

Tags: halacha, gentiles, torah-study

Are non-Jews allowed to watch online videos of shiurim, and if so, how would a Gentile know if he or she is permitted to watch it?

As a non-Jew, I like spending time watching YouTube videos of rabbis (i.e. Rabbi Yosef Mizrachi, Rabbi Tovia Singer, Rabbi Alon Anava) giving lectures on various Torah subjects as I find them to be spiritually enlightening. Since these videos are posted online and accessible to the public, I have to assume that anyone is permitted to watch them. My concern (perhaps I'm overly concerned) however is that there may be some material that non-Jews are forbidden to watch/listen to even though it's accessible online. If so, how can I determine if that's the case?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you or your concern and the sensitive way you bring your question to this forum. There is no law preventing anyone from watching Jewish lectures.

There are seven laws relevant for non-Jews, called the seven Noahide laws (as they were given to Noah, the father of all of humanity). In one explanation (see [here](http://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/62221/jewish/Universal-Morality.htm))

> [the first of the seven laws is] to acknowledge there is only one God who is
>   Infinite and Supreme above all things. [...] This command includes
>   such acts as prayer, study and meditation.

As such, if you watch online lectures to further your understanding of God and his commandments as they apply to you, you are actually fulfilling God's laws for non-Jews (see [here](http://www.aish.com/w/nj/For_Non-Jews.html) for more on the seven laws).

It is true that the Talmud writes that a gentile is not permitted to study Torah and Jews from teaching it to them. Related to your case, one of last generation's leading sages, Rabbi Moshe Feinstein rules that one is permitted to teach Torah to Jews while a non-Jew is listening (Igros Moshe, Yoreh Deah 2:132) (taken from [here](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=14572)). And all agree that one is permitted to teach non-Jews about their obligations. See [here](http://www.jpost.com/Magazine/Judaism/Ask-the-rabbi-May-a-Jew-teach-Torah-to-a-gentile) and [here](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=14572) if you wish to learn more.

See also [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23042/non-jews-learning-or-being-taught-torah) for a related question on MY.

Comment: But the Igrot Moshe doesn't say that the non-Jews may learn, and certainly doesn't say that they may seek out the information, just that a Jew isn't forbidden from teaching Jews Torah if a non-Jew will hear.

Comment: So what's the answer? That everything other than the 7 mitsvot is prohibited?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding a non-Jew intending to convert is allowed to learn Gemara.

As for not intending to convert but listening for the sake of spiritual enlightenment, the Torah does say something like "Israel will be a light to the nations", and it says that in the messianic era, knowledge of God will be plentiful and everyone will know it, and it also says that 10 non-Jews will chase after one Jew wanting to learn the truth.

But if someone wants to learn Torah in order to cast doubt anyway they can (like heretics and atheists) then I don't think that is allowed.

Comment: I think that you need to go into more detail. Note that the OP does not say that he intends to convert.

Comment: @sabbahillel updated answer as suggested.