# List of what noahides can’t observe

Tags: gentiles, jewish-books, noahide

Is there a Sefer or article that gives a comprehensive list of what mitzvot noahides can and can not observe (beyond the basic understanding of the  7 laws) Furthermore, what voluntary mitzvot noahides are allowed to make a Berakhah over? Thanks, sources for claims are very valuable and appreciated

Comment: The question was meant to be about what noahides are and are not allowed to observe, not what they are commanded in. I edited it for you @RabbiKaii to make it more clear

Comment: Great, got it now, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend the sefer called "The Divine Commandment" by Rabbi Moshe Weiner. I have been told for Chabad, it is considered "The Shulchan Aruch for Noahides" .

To answer your question what a Noahide cannot observe, refer to what Rabbi Weiner [says](https://asknoah.org/faq/going_beyond):

> Gentiles are especially forbidden to perform commandments that require the holiness of a Jew, such as writing a scroll of the Torah or a mezuzah or phylacteries (tefillin in Hebrew).
> The general rule is that any Jewish mitzvah between man and man, or between man and G-d, which has a reason and a logical benefit for a person or society, is permitted for Gentiles to perform. But this does not apply for any commandment that does not have a logical, natural benefit, but is rather a sign for the Jews (e.g., wearing ritual fringes [tzitzit] or phylacteries, or affixing a mezuzah on a doorpost), or is a G-dly statute for the Jews without reason or benefit understood to a person [as to logically how and why the ritual would bring any natural benefit]. A Gentile should be prevented from performing such commandments and should be taught that it is improper for him to observe them.

The Gemara also explains that a Noahide can study Torah in-depth, but only with regard to subjects on the seven Noahide laws. Also, Shabbos is one of the mitzvos, they should not observe.

Besides that, as @Dov wrote in his answer, Noahides have the seven Noahide laws which they should observe.

To [summarize](https://asknoah.org/faq/going_beyond):

> In summary, Gentiles should first and foremost understand and follow their Seven Noahide Commandments that G-d requires of them, for which the reward granted to the Torah-faithful pious Noahides is a place in the future eternal World to Come. With this commitment, a Gentile should start learning and keeping the Seven Noahide Commandments in the proper way, as they are explained within the Torah Law received by Moses from G-d at Mount Sinai. Under the guidance of an Orthodox Rabbi or mentor, this can certainly include the study of Chassidic discourses and teachings that are relevant to the Noahide Code. A good additional observance to begin following is to give properly directed charity, and to give often [even daily, and even if it is only a small amount that is dropped into a charity can or box in one’s home].

Regarding the famous question regarding Torah study and being a Noahide, please see [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/97340/27180) question and the answer(s) there. In the Hebrew equivalent of "The Divine Code", sefer  שבע מצות השם (Chapter 3, p. 36 sv. איסור חידוש דרג והוספת מצוה) the basis for this prohibiton is that Torah is the "morasha kehilas Yaakov", the inheritance of the Jewish people. It is forbidden to teach a Noahide Torah that is not about the Seven Noahide Laws. Refer to [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/gentiles-learning-torah-may-one-teach-torah-to-a-gentile/).

With regard to saying berachos - blessings - the sefer Sheva Mitzos Hashem (Chapter 6, sv. עבודת השם תפלה וברכת המזון , p. 74) says that although Noahides are not obligated to say a beracha, there is nevertheless no objection in thanking G-d for granting him food to eat, or to drink. He should thank G-d that he can partake in the meal etc..

Furthermore it says that it is appropriate to request from G-d that what he eats or drinks, will sustain him and be good for him. So yes, in some sense, a beracha could be made by a Noahide.

The Hebrew version is available on [Otzar HaChochmah](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/143243/p/1/t/2476287881234/fs/xzuZxqrmNFDibzdchHyutjgRx5FwJvdywu7w8jTsc6X0/start/0/end/14/c). The English version can be bought [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0719SDQVM).

Comment: But a non jew is permitted to bring an offering to the temple - a man/god mitzva without natural benefit!

Comment: @ClintEastwood, he can only bring an offering that is brought as a Nedavah - voluntary offering

Comment: So? Why shouldn't he be taught it is improper?

Answer (score 0):

See famously [Sanhedrin 56a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.56a.24?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> תנו רבנן שבע מצות נצטוו בני נח דינין וברכת השם ע"ז גילוי עריות ושפיכות דמים וגזל ואבר מן החי
>
> Our Rabbis taught in a baraisa: The descendants of Noah, (i.e. all of humanity) were commanded to observe seven mitzvos: The mitzva of establishing courts of judgment; and the prohibition against blessing, i.e. cursing, the name of God; and the prohibition of idol worship; and the prohibition against forbidden sexual relations; and the prohibition of bloodshed; and the prohibition of robbery; and the prohibition against eating a limb from a living animal.

---

**EDIT**

Beyond these seven I would recommend this article [here](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/14572) from [Rabbi Yirmiyohu Kaganoff](https://rabbikaganoff.com/about/) who notes:

> In addition to the "Seven Mitzvos," there are other activities that are also prohibited to a non-Jew. According to some opinions, **a non-Jew may not graft trees from different species or crossbreed animals** (Sanhedrin 56b; [Rambam Hilchos Melachim 10:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.10.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); Meiri ad loc.; cf. [Shach Yoreh Deah 297:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Siftei_Kohen_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.297.3.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) and [Dagul Mei’re’vavah](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7631&st=&pgnum=78&hilite=) ad loc.; [Chazon Ish Kilayim 1:1](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14335&st=&pgnum=83&hilite=)). Some poskim even prohibit a non-Jew from owning a grafted fruit tree, and a Jew may not sell him such a tree because he is causing a non-Jew to violate his mitzvah (Shu’t Mahar"i Asad, Yoreh Deah #350; [Shu’t Maharsham 1:179](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1386&st=&pgnum=185&hilite=)).
>
> Some poskim contend that non-Jews are prohibited from engaging in **sorcery** (see [Kesef Mishneh, Hilchos Avodah Zarah, 11:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Kessef_Mishneh_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.11.4.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). According to this opinion, a non-Jew may not use any type of black magic, necromancy, or fortune telling. However, most opinions disagree (Radbaz to Hilchos Melachim 10:6).

Comment: I asked what noahides can’t observe, I know what they are obligated in @dov

Comment: @KirkBellard you said "...a comprehensive list of what mitzvot noahides can and can not observe?" These are the fundamental 7 :-)

Comment: Yes, CAN and CAN NOT, not HAVE TO. @dov