# What is allowed to be studied during conversion?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

I have been studying on my own for a year in order to convert to Judaism (Orthodox) as my current job doesn't allow me, moving every week, to settle next to a jewish community and formally launch the process with a Rabbi. I am due to change my job occupation in 2 months.

Are converts authorized to study out of curiosity mishnayot or gemara for example ? Are we allowed to study anything if we already have a reasonable understanding of the basics ?

I understand that there is a prohibition for gentiles to study Torah for other purposes than practicing the 7 Noahide laws to become a righteous gentile but what is allowed for people in the process of converting to Judaism ? Talmud ? Mishnayot ? Halakha ? Midrash ?

Many books for converts frequently quote from the Gemara and I have even seen mishnayot. Is it considered issur for people converting to study them or be accidentally exposed to them as both Written and Oral Torah are both morasha of the Jewish people ?

I know the question can seem stupid as I have already (superficially studied) these sources and your answer may probably refer and/or quote from these very sources. I did not know beforehand nor thought about prohibitions which would pertain to studying for gentiles.

I would like very much to know what is the halakha as I have stopped for the time being studying anything else other than Torah and commentaries while waiting for an answer.

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23042/non-jews-learning-or-being-taught-torah and https://etzion.org.il/en/halakha/studies-halakha/philosophy-halakha/non-jews-and-talmud-torah

Comment: This question is not about the subject of what a non-Jew is permitted to study. It is focussing specifically on an individual who is intending and preparing to convert. It is not a duplicate.