Are non-Jews who are converting to Judaism allowed to read the Talmud?
A general question, I’ve been curious about. Are non-Jews who are converting to Judaism allowed to read the Talmud?

Welcome to MiYodeya Danny and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

relevant: What are the parameters of the prohibition against a non-Jew learning Torah? and Non-Jews learning or being taught Torah

Most of the answers I see are rules applicable to Noahides, who are not converting. I am interested in knowing the laws for people in process of converting. Can they read/study the Talmud (specifically under the guidance of the Rabbi, if not alone since it’s a complex text).

This will be the right question, but it is closed. I've voted to reopen it: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/140735/what-is-allowed-to-be-studied-during-conversion

@Danny this would be a great question to ask the rabbi assisting this particular convert. Now you should know that (1) one does not read the Talmud, one studies it, and it requires a lot of background, (2) one who reads it will not understand what is meant to be conveyed, (3) there is so much else to study before one gets to the Talmud, esp. for a convert starting from scratch. So the question is actually not so relevant except for the intellectual curiosity of knowing "what's in there". Reading a few pages superficially is not an issue, it is not really called learning

The "version" of Judaism a prospective convert learns about is infused with the talmud. It is hard to "read" the text that is Judaism withOUT reading the talmud.

https://www.sefaria.org/Contemporary_Halakhic_Problems%2C_Vol_II%2C_Part_II%2C_Chapter_XVI_Teaching_Torah_to_Non_Jews.82?lang=bi
